Number of inequivalent binary matrices with a restriction
This question is about $n$ by $n$ binary matrices.
We say that two matrices are equivalent if one can be transformed into the other by row and column permutations.
Define a matrix to be bare if it has:

no row containing at most one one
no column containing at most one one
all rows are distinct

There are, for example, no bare 2 by 2 matrices.
The two bare 3 by 3 matrices (up to equivalence) are:
0 1 1 
1 1 0
1 0 1

0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1

An example bare 4 by 4 matrix is:
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1

The counts for $n = 2,3,4,5,6$ are $0, 2, 20, 570,  46551$.
How many inequivalent bare $n$ by $n$ binary matrices are there for $n>2$?

What have you tried? I recommend listing out all of them for small $n$, and then looking up the sequence in OEIS.

I would look at Pólya's enumeration theorem

@JairTaylor It's not in the OEIS sadly.

One way to rephrase the question (maybe helps with searching for results) is the following: Consider the matrix as the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph $G=(V\cup V', E)$ of $n+n$ vertices (1 in $A_{ij}$ if there is an edge from $V_i$ to $V_j'$). Then you are looking for the number of isomorphism classes (isomorphism may not map vertices from $V$ to $V'$ or vice versa) of graphs without twins (nodes with same neighborhood) and with minimum degree two.

For any natural $n$ let $a_n$ be the number of bare $n\times n$ matrices. We show that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ grows very fast and evaluate its growth rate.
Fix any natural $n\ge 2$. Since there are $2^n-n-1$ admissible rows for a bare matrix, we have $$a_n\le {2^n-n-1\choose n}\le\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}.$$
On the other hand, choose binary entries of an $n\times n$ matrix independently with the probability $1/2$ each value. Then the probability that the matrix will be bare is at least
$$\left(1-\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)^{2n},\mbox{ so } a_n\ge \left(1-\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)^{2n}\cdot \frac{2^{n^2}}{n!^2}.$$
Thus $$\log a_n=n^2\log 2+O(n).$$
